# TRAVIS CI : ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: django, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I have created a sample project [Django/Python] in a private repo on GitHub. Recently, I have a added a sample .travis.yml file to it in order to get CI rolling. Now issue is my tests [I am using Pytest suite] pass when I run the command `pytest` on my local machine. But I am unable to get my test suite running on `Travis` because of the above mentioned error. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Here's my sample `.travis.yml` file.

```
language: python
sudo: false
python:
- '3.6.4'

services:
  - mysql

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - mysql-5.7-trusty
    packages:
      - mysql-server

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.cache/pip

before_install:
  - sudo mysql -e "use mysql; update user set password=PASSWORD('123123') where User='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
  - sudo service mysql restart

before_cache:
  - rm -f $HOME/.cache/pip/log/debug.log

install:
  - pip install -r requirements/development.txt

before_script:
- sudo mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE my_database;'

script:
- flake8
- pytest --cov -v --tb=native

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: change  # [always|never|change]
    on_failure: always  # [always|never|change]
```

Just to add one more piece of info. My DB settings are as follows : 
`settings.py`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_database',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use the username `travis` or `root` with a blank password? It's in their docs; https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#mysql

Answer (score 0):

In your `.travis.yml` use this to change the password:

```
before_install:
  - sudo mysql -e "use mysql; update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('123123') where User='root'; update user set plugin='mysql_native_password';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
  - sudo mysql_upgrade -u root -p123123
  - sudo service mysql restart
```

Or it's always best to use `root` or `travis` as username and leave the password blank.

Comment: I tried using this. Now I am getting the following error in the `travis-ci` console. 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
The command "mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE my_database;'" failed and exited with 1 during .